# how to hide a successful modal box upon an incomplete form submission

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

i've read through several other questions similar to this, but none seemed to work for some reason.

i have a simple ajax form, and upon successful submission a modal box that says 'Successful!...' pops up. however, for some reason, this modal box also pops up when the form is incomplete/has errors, which is obviously problematic.

here's the .js for the modal box. what needs to be added or changed?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#ajax_form_cancel_request').submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

            if($('#ajax_form_cancel_request')[0].checkValidity() ){
                $('#confirm-message').modal('toggle');
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you provide a JSbin or Fiddler exmaple?

Comment: i've been trying to put together a .js fiddle now, but there's so much .js code on the page i'm having trouble trying to filter out what's needed or not needed. our web master has been furloughed, and only works a few hours at the end of the week, and i've been giving the task of fixing this. i have only a basic understanding of how .js works. i should have one put together soon